# How do I run sass on react using npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass

After **installing** SASS on my ReachJs file with NPM, I keep getting this error code. I have gone through several documentations on installing SASS with NPM but cant seem to wrap my head around how to make it work. This is what the error code looks like on my cmd...

```
./src/homepage.styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/homepage.styles.scss)
    margin: 0 7.5px 15px;

                 ^
  Invalid CSS after "...: 0 7.5px 15px;": expected "}", was "&: first-child {"
  in C:\Users\user\Desktop\corpers\src\homepage.styles.scss (line 22, column 23)
```

[

meanwhile, this is the SASS code

```
.menu-item {
min-width: 30%;
height: 240px;
flex: 1 1 auto;
display-items: center;
justify-content: center;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 7.5px 15px;       

    &: first-child {
        margin-right: 7.5px;
    }

    &: last-child {
        margin-left: 7.5px;
    }

    .content {
        height: 90px;
        padding: 0.25px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 1px solid black;

        .title {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 6px;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: #4a4a4a;
        }

        .subtitle {
            font-weighr: lighter;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

}[\]\[1\][1]
```

Comment: Looking at the first line of your error message, `./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?`
your `scss` file still seems to be processed by the `css-loader`. Are you using webpack? how are have you configured the sass-loader you installed?

Answer (score 0):

So i figured a way. I needed to delete my npm.lock and node_modules in my create-react-app, then yarn install in my cmd. Once that was done, everything started working properly.
The logic is that npm and yarn are not compatible, so once i used npm to create-react-app, it naturally downloaded the react library. However, there are some dependancies that arenot compatible with yarn which needed to be deleted for the yarn install to work at all.